# WPF/C# webbrowser youtube

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube

I want to play youtube movie in my application by using webbrowser.

The problem is about autoplay movies.

I know i can use embeded, but on embeded version its impossible to navigate the website.

Is there any solution how to autoplay youtube movies?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a specific control 'COM' to show a movie 'swf' in a form, called 'Shockwave Flash Object'

And Swf Url Movie:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/[CODE VIDEO]&autoplay=1
```

Comment: Its same like embeded i want to play video in youtube website.

Answer (score 0):

Google have actually made available an API which allows you to do this kind of thing across all platforms, whether it be in a web or application interface. You can find the documentation for it [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/). But as a guide, here is what you can do....

All you have to do is replace parts of the URL, which can be done easily with string manipulation. I have specifed link a - which is the normal youtube link, and b - which is the API link which can play in full screen mode (or size of your frame or web browser) and many other features which you can command through the URL.

a - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuLPSz_Hffw

b - http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/DuLPSz_Hffw?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&loop=1

Hope that helps!

Comment: Its same like embeded i want to play video in youtube website.